# What's another way to say the structure of something was broken apart?

Tags: synonyms

To clarify, I'm trying to say that because of xyz, it became more difficult for ABC to be targeted and broken apart.

ABC is a business empire, so attacked and other military-related words aren't as helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Actually, "broken up" would be reasonably idiomatic for your example.

Comment: Businesses are often ***split up***

Answer (score 1):

because of xyz, it became more difficult for ABC to be **disaggregated**.

> Definition of **disaggregate** 
>   transitive verb.
>   : to separate into component part.
>   - [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disaggregate)

Answer (score 0):

A business can be **re-structured**  [Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/restructure)

> construct or form anew or provide with a new structure

The verb restructure can refer to a company that is changing the way it operates in order to be more efficient.

> Tencent announced a **restructuring** that created a new
>   division focused on business services such as cloud computing. Wall
>   Street Journal Nov 12, 2018

or

**dismantle**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/dismantle)

> To take apart; disassemble; tear down.

```
Synonyms:  break apart, break up, take apart
```

> Volkswagen’s Truck & Bus division, which houses the MAN and Scania
>   brands, may follow a wider trend among carmakers and suppliers to
>   **dismantle** conglomerates into more specialized businesses.
>       Reuters Mar 4, 2018

The title of you question and the sentence example in your question have slightly different meanings:

Because of xyz, it became more difficult for ABC to be targeted and broken apart.

could become:

Because of xyz, it became more difficult for ABC to be **re-structured**/ **dismantled**.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the word: dissolution.

> Due to XYZ, ABC's dissolution became an impossibility.